# no validates_attachment_file_name when upgrading to Paperclip 4.1 from 3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, paperclip-validation

We have code that looks like run of the mill paper clip:

```
has_merchants_attached_file :pdf,
    storage:          :s3, 
    s3_credentials:   Mbc::DataStore.s3_credentials,
    s3_permissions:   :private,
    path:             ":identifier_template.pdf",
    bucket:           Mbc::DataStore.forms_and_templates_bucket_name


  validates_attachment_file_name :pdf, :matches => [/pdf\Z/]
```

Which generates an error:

```
undefined method `validates_attachment_file_name' for #<Class:0x007fba67d25fe0>
```

Interestingly enough, when we down grade back to 3.5, we encounter the same issue.

The controller that is generating this is:

```
def index
   @fidelity_templates = FidelityTemplate.order("identifier asc").all
end
```

Additionally:

```
def has_merchants_attached_file(attribute, options={})
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
     has_attached_file attribute,
     path: "paperclip_attachments/#{options[:path]}"
  else
    has_attached_file attribute, options
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean by `has_merchants_attached_file`? Is it your own method? If yes, could you please share it.

Comment: @KirtiThorat. No I didn't. It is from the documentation as noted below.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? Can you please point it.

Comment: @KirtiThorat https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations

Comment: I looked at "Security Validations" section. I don't see `has_merchants_attached_file` method mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry. @KirtiThorat, I've added it above.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about the provided validators here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations

The included validators are:

- AttachmentContentTypeValidator
- AttachmentPresenceValidator
- AttachmentSizeValidator

They can be used in either of these ways:

```
# New style:
validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :avatar

# Old style:
validates_attachment_presence :avatar
```

UPDATE ...

If you read further down the link I've given above you'll get to a section on Security Validations (Thanks Kirti Thorat):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations

They give an example on how to validate the filename format:

```
# Validate filename
validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
```

From your code snippet it looks like your validation should work as-is.

However, I've never seen paperclip used with this syntax:

```
has_merchants_attached_file ...
```

Perhaps that's the source of your issues? You would usually use the following to attach files to your model:

```
has_attached_file :pdf ...
```

Comment: Check the `Security Validations` section which is right under the `Validations section` in Paperclip gitrepo. OP is trying to do that.