# Multiple validations for the same file in Paperclip [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I want to have a way to do something similar (This is psuedo code)

```
if file == image
size = 2mb
else if file == audio
size = 5mb
end
```

That I can do with validations as I want anything I upload to take on different restrictions like file size depending on the type of file uploaded.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations

I'll post my current model below

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

      do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file

      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

      def to_jq_upload
        {
          "name" => read_attribute(:file_file_name),
          "size" => read_attribute(:file_file_size),
          "url" => file.url(:original),
          "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
          "delete_type" => "DELETE"
        }
      end
    end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something we did a while back (not sure if it still works with the [recent Paperclip upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910714/upgrading-to-paperclip-4-1-from-3-5)):

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :attachment
     validates_attachment :size => Proc.new {|attachment
        if attachment.is_image?
            15mb
        elsif attachment.is_audio?
            2mb
        end
     }

     private

     def is_image?
         attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
     end

     def is_audio?
         attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(audio)
     end

end
```